# django getting current user id

Tags: django, post, get, request

i have a mini app where users can login, view their profile, and follow each other. 
'Follow' is a relation like a regular 'friend' relationship in virtual communities, but it is not necessarily reciprocal, meaning that one can follow a user, without the need that the user to be following back that person who follows him.
my problem is: 
if i am a logged in user, and i navigate to a profile X, and push the button follow, how can i take the current profile id ?(current profile meaning the profile that I, the logged in user, am viewing right now.)

the view:

```
   def follow(request):
      if request.method == 'POST':
    form = FollowForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
    new_obj = form.save(commit=False)
    new_obj.initiated_by = request.user
    u = User.objects. what here?
    new_obj.follow = u   
    new_obj.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('.')    
   else:
       form = FollowForm()     
   return render_to_response('followme/follow.html', {
       'form': form,
       }, 
      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the user's profile to your form, you can pass it in with your post.

There are a number of ways to do it. You could add a hidden field to your FollowForm (pass in the profile as an instance).

You could do it more manually by inserting a hidden field such as:

```
<input type="hidden" name="profile_id" value="{{ profile.id }}" />
```

Then you could change your code above to:

```
u = User.objects.get(request.POST['profile_id'])
```

Or, perhaps you already have the profile's user id in your view?

Comment: it seems right, but i get an error : need more than 1 value to unpack

and i don't see why i have more than one value in the declaration of u.
thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Try `request.user.id`. But there is a better good practice. let me see.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/optimization/ is a good start and is full of good practice.
In your case, use `request.user.id`.

Comment: yep. the idea is not to take the id of the current logged in user (in my above example i am logged in) but the id of the user whose profile i am visiting and i want to follow.
Thank you very much for interest!

Comment: ok, imagine the url of the profile is something like /user/<id>/, then the action to follow a certain people can be resumed to a POST on an url like /user/<id>/follow/ where id is the user.id of the people you want to follow.

Comment: yes. it seems logical, and right :) i'll try it now, and post the results. thanks ! :)

Comment: nope, i see now:) the problem is that i don't have the user id in the url, so i can't take it from POST:(